# How to implement joins efficiently if lookup id are in embedded docs mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider a scenario a `user` can subscribe many `channels` and the `channel` belongs to a `publisher`

**Basically there are three entities**

1: user

2: channel

3: publisher

**Below is sample saved data in db:**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a7428b7408437d7155bbde9"),
  "name" : "some subscriber who is a user ",
    "channelSubscription" : {
      "5a740c88408437d7155bbdca" : {
      "_id" : "5a740c88408437d7155bbdca",
      "channel_name" : "1st channel",
      "channelBelongsTo" : "publisher._id" // replace id with publisher details
   },

    "5a7411dc408437d7155bbdcb" : {
       "_id" : "5a7411dc408437d7155bbdcb",
       "channel_name" : "2nd channel",
       "channelBelongsTo" : "someOtherPublisher._id" // replace id with publisher details
     }
   }
}
```

How can I make joins here to fetch `publisher` details, so that `channelBelongsTo` can have publisher details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the aggregation framework here to achieve the desired result. The aggregate pipeline should initially create a new field that is an array of key/value pairs of the hashmap, made possible using the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)** pipeline step and the $objectToArray operator. So your first pipeline step would be:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
       "$addFields": {
           "subscriptions": { "$objectToArray": "$channelSubscription" }
       } 
    }
])
```

which yields

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7428b7408437d7155bbde9"),
    "name" : "some subscriber who is a user ",
    "channelSubscription" : {
        "5a740c88408437d7155bbdca" : {
            "_id" : "5a740c88408437d7155bbdca",
            "channel_name" : "1st channel",
            "channelBelongsTo" : "1"
        },
        "5a7411dc408437d7155bbdcb" : {
            "_id" : "5a7411dc408437d7155bbdcb",
            "channel_name" : "2nd channel",
            "channelBelongsTo" : "2"
        }
    },
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "5a740c88408437d7155bbdca",
            "v" : {
                "_id" : "5a740c88408437d7155bbdca",
                "channel_name" : "1st channel",
                "channelBelongsTo" : "1"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "5a7411dc408437d7155bbdcb",
            "v" : {
                "_id" : "5a7411dc408437d7155bbdcb",
                "channel_name" : "2nd channel",
                "channelBelongsTo" : "2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

For the join you will need to append the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** pipeline step which fetches the `publisher` details, given by:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
       "$addFields": {
           "subscriptions": { "$objectToArray": "$channelSubscription" }
       } 
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "publisher",
            "localField": "subscriptions.v.channelBelongsTo",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "publishers"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: didn't worked publishers is coming out to be blank array

Comment: Hi, got it where I was doing wrong, `"localField": "subscriptions.v.channelBelongsTo"` was stored as a `string` not as an `objectId` thankyou !!